# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have problem when print output list of people by using ArrayList

```
package data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {
List<Person> p = new ArrayList();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void addStudent() {
    String id;
    String name;
    int yob;
    double point1;
    double point2;
    System.out.println("Input student id:");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input student name:");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input yob:");
    yob = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Input point 1:");
    point1 = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Input point 2:");
    point2 = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
    p.add(new Student(id,name,yob,point1,point2));
}
public void addEmployee() {
    String id;
    String name;
    int yob;
    double salaryRatio;
    double salary;
    System.out.println("Input employee id:");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input employee name:");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input employee yob:");
    yob = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Input salary ratio:");
    salaryRatio = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Input salary:");
    salary = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
    p.add(new Employee(id, name, yob,salaryRatio, salary));
}
public void addCustomer() {
    String id;
    String name;
    int yob;
    String companyName;
    double bill;
    System.out.println("Input customer id:");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input customer name:");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input customer yob:");
    yob = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Input compnay name:");
    companyName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input bill:");
    bill = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
    p.add(new Customer(id,name,yob,companyName,bill));
}
public void addWho() {
    int choice;
    do {
    System.out.println("1.Add Student");
    System.out.println("2.Add Employee");
    System.out.println("3.Add Customer");
    System.out.println("4.Back to menu");
    System.out.println("==============");
    System.out.println("Choice:");
    choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            addStudent();
            break;
        case 2:
            addEmployee();
            break;
        case 3:
            addCustomer();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
    }
    }
    while(choice != 4);
}
public void printPersonById() {
    Collections.sort(p, Comparator.comparing(Person::getId));
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(p.get(i));
    }
}
```

Student,Employee, and Customer are sub classes of class Person.When I **try to** **print list**,it has an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

How can I fix it?

Comment: In which line you get the exception? Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Is this really on Android? The use of `System.in` makes that unlikely... please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you override the `toString()` Method in `Person`, `Studend`, `Employee` or `Customer`?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

use `System.out.println(p.get(i).someMethodOrVariableOfPerson);` instead of `System.out.println(p.get(i));`

**like below**

```
    public void printPersonById() {
        Collections.sort(p, Comparator.comparing(Person::getId));
        for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("id :"+p.get(i).id);
            System.out.println("name :"+p.get(i).name);

        }
    }
```

you can not directly print Person class object in out.println() method.
out.println() allow only string value

Comment: But I wanna print all value of Person Objects,so which method I should use for it? I coded an app like it but only have 1 Object, and I can print it in that way.

Comment: Show me your person model class

Comment: package data;
public class Person {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected int yob;  contructor; getter and setter; toString;

Comment: check my updated answer above if its not work then make person class variable public instead of protected

Comment: I know your way although using public, it's still not working.Tks bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
System.out.println("Input yob:");
yob = sc.nextInt(); 
System.out.println("Input point 1:"); point1 =sc.nextDouble(); 
System.out.println("Input point 2:"); point2 = sc.nextDouble(); 
p.add(new Student(id,name,yob,point1,point2));
```

Comment: It's the same as I use Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) instead of using sc.nexInt() or sc.nextDouble()